# How to create light beam effect? (Alone in the Dark opening)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

How to make this light beam effect on any object, be it text, a cube, one or a single beam from which the beams of light emanates, and give it the movement similar to that in the image?

[image]

I add this image, I had an idea of how it was, but I have no experience with this area of FX, or light games

[image]

[in this video everything is made with blender, in this part in particular it shows a beam of light similar to the effect of the letters, so if it can be achieved, I just don't know how to do it](https://youtu.be/b2PD10cehHs?t=29)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the [animation-nodes] tag intended here? Do you want to use the Animation Nodes addon?

Comment: I am honest, touching the topic of cycles I declare myself ignorant, I had just used blender render (internal, for convenience) since I have to travel constantly for work or school and if I can not use my lap that is very basic, I use a tablet also very basic for modeling, and I can hardly enjoy my desktop pc so I was unable to use the dedicated gpu

Comment: and for this I am open to learn because it is a subject that I need to learn and understand today

Answer (score 2):

You could try with a cube encompassing your scene, and you plug a *Volume Scatter* node into its *Volume* Output to create a mist. I'm personally struggling with this solution so here is a solution with compositing that comes not too far.

It must be much easier with Eevee and the *Principled Volume*, but your question is for Cycles and I can't make Eevee work on my computer.

I guess it can be improved:

- Create your title. Give it a black *Diffuse* node, put in front of your camera. Duplicate the title, put it behind the black version and on another layer, in *Edit* mode extrude a bit and scale it a bit with *Shrink/Fatten*, give it a white *Emission* node, with a *Strength* of 2.

[image]

- In the *Render* panel > *Film*, enable *Transparent* so that you layers are transparent. In the *Node Editor / Compositing*, organize your nodes: Basically you need to mix (*Alpha Over*) the render layer with the black title with the render layer with the white title. I put some blur here and there, but the important things are to put a *Sun Beams* effect after the white title and a *Glare* effect just before the *Output*. The *Sun Beam* will create the beams behind, the *Glare* will fake a bit of glow in front of the black title. And you can move the *Sun Beam* X and Y value as if the spot was moving behind.

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: This incredible looks very good, I liked it a lot, now let me see if I understand correctly, I can create my animation of movement of the light beam with this?, you can detract more the has of light, and that it does not look like a halo

Comment: yes you can move the light with the X and Y values of Sun Beam node, the halo thing is because I've fattened the white title and gave some blur nodes + the final Glow, I guess everything is improvable, the only thing is that you can't make the light beams coming in front of the letters if you see what I mean, you can only fake it with a Glow effect or some other effect. But again, if you can, try with Eevee, the mist seems much easier to deal with, and you can also play with Bloom and some compositing...

Comment: add a new image, I had an idea of how it was, but I have no experience with this area of FX, or light games

Comment: Yes try other ways, mine is just a solution among others I guess   ;)   my solution use the Compositing, I don't know a lot myself about compositing, so it must be improvable

Comment: Well I am but in composition, at least you have this, I have not been able to abound that topic, so in nodes I don't have many skills